# Join table using columns which contains other table's id's separated by commas

Tags: sql, join

I have FACULTY table which contain the column with other table's id's separated by commas. I want to join those with respective table.

`faculty` table:

```
id | name  | course_id | subject_id
a  | smith | 2,3       | 1,2
```

`course` table:

```
id | name
1  | bcom
2  | mcom
3  | bba
```

`subject` table:

```
id | name
1  | account
2  | state
3  | economics
```

I want to get result from these table like..

```
faculty.id, faculty.name, course.name(using faculty.course_id), subject.name(using faculty.subject_id)
```

I have tried a lot of queries and also finds from Google but it didn't gave me proper result.

Comment: Can you show the query that you tried?

Comment: I would really suggest that you break out the comma separated values into separate tables so that you can join normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following query

```
  select * from faculty F
     JOIN course C
          on CHARINDEX((','+CAST(c.id as varchar(10))+','), (','+f.courseid+',')) > 0
     JOIN subject s
          on CHARINDEX((','+CAST(s.id as varchar(10))+','), (','+f.subjectid+',')) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the performance will be too nice but worths trying. This solution would work in `SQL SERVER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM faculty F
     JOIN course C
         ON ','+F.course_id+',' LIKE '%,'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,C.ID) +',%'
     JOIN subject S
         ON ','+F.subject_id_id+',' LIKE '%,'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,S.ID) +',%'
```

Based on `Albin Sunnanbo`'s comment i would also sugget you add some many too many tables:

**fcourses**

```
facultyId 
courseId
```

and

**fsubjects**

```
facultyId
subjectId
```

That way you could do a proper join :

```
SELECT *
FROM faculty F
     JOIN fcourses FC
         ON F.Id = FC.facultyId
     JOIN course C
         ON FC.courseId = C.ID
     JOIN fsubjects FS
         ON F.Id = FS.facultyId
     JOIN subject S
         ON FS.courseId = S.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar like this:

```
select f.id, f.lname, f.fname, U.useridlist
from TABLE1 F, TABLE2 U
where ',' || U.useridlist || ',' like '%,' || f.id || ',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a 'string to int table' function, I would look at the following:

**Create the function**

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ConvertIntListToTable] (@list varchar(MAX))
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (val int) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ix int,
@pos int,
@str varchar(MAX),
@num int
SET @pos = 1
SET @ix = 1
WHILE @ix > 0
BEGIN
SET @ix = charindex(',', @list, @pos)
IF @ix > 0
SET @str = substring(@list, @pos, @ix - @pos)
ELSE
SET @str = substring(@list, @pos, len(@list))
SET @str = ltrim(rtrim(@str))
IF @str LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND
(@str NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' OR
@str LIKE '[-+]%' AND
substring(@str, 2, len(@str)) NOT LIKE '[-+]%[^0-9]%')
BEGIN
SET @num = convert(int, @str)
INSERT @tbl (val) VALUES(@num)
END
SET @pos = @ix + 1
END
RETURN
END
```

**Then query using CROSS APPLY**

```
declare @FacultyTable table(id int PRIMARY KEY, name nvarchar(50), course_id varchar(50))
declare @CourseTable table(id int PRIMARY KEY, name nvarchar(50))

insert into @FacultyTable values(1, 'Peter Sagal', '11,22')
insert into @FacultyTable values(2, 'Carl Kasell', '22,33')

insert into @CourseTable values(11,'News')
insert into @CourseTable values(22,'News')
insert into @CourseTable values(33,'News')
insert into @CourseTable values(44,'News')


select *
from @FacultyTable f
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT *
        FROM @CourseTable c
        WHERE
            c.id IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_ConvertIntListToTable(f.course_id))

    ) tCourses
```